# Customize Bibliographystlye kluwer

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, harvard-style

In LaTex, I would like to have a customized bibliographystyle. So far, I use the natbib package and the kluwer style. My .bib file is automatically created with Mendeley. Citations in the text work fine, but the reference section does not look the way it is supposed. 
Depending on the publication type, I want different entries:
[image]

So, e.g. for a conference proceeding I want:

Muster, S. and Muller, A. (2017), ``Testing ...", in *Workshop,* Springer, Cham, pp. 65-71.

For now, I get:

Muster, S. and Muller, A.: 2017, Testing ..., *Workshop,* Springer, Cham, pp. 65-71.

My .bib Entry (automatically generated by Mendeley) looks like this:

```
@inproceedings{Muster2017,
author = {Muster, Sebastian and Muller, Anna},
booktitle = {Workshop},
pages = {65--71},
publisher = {Springer, Cham},
title = {{Testing ...}},
year = {2017}
}
```

Here is a mini-example code for LaTex. Please save the Code above as test.bib

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer} 
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 

\begin{document} 

Like \citep{Muster2017}.

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Any help is appricated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You've told us how you'd like to see an entry of type `@inproceedings` formatted. But what about entries of type `@article`, `@book`, `@misc`, `@techreport`, `@unpublished`, etc, etc.? Hacking an existing bibliography style can very quickly become very complicated and error-prone. As an alternative, do look into using the `makebst` utility (part of the `custom-bib` package) to create a bespoke bibliography style from scratch. The utility poses a series of questions, each with multiple possible answers (and 1 of the possible answers highlighted as the default). Do give it a try.

Comment: Thank you  @Mico! 
My picture showed how entries of other types should look like.
I tried makebst, it worked perfectly :)